# Problema con Tkinter en MAC

Tags: python, tkinter, macos

Tengo un problema con Tkinter, estoy usando Mojave y Visual Studio Code, les comparto mi código aunque yo creo que es un problema de instalación de python, se supone que tkinter debe venir junto a la version 3 de python pero no logro poder usarlo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

UPDATE
Este es mi error como puedes ver abajo estoy usando la versión 3.7 de python[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Aqui te dejo como me quedó]

Comment: copia por favor el texto del código, será mucho más fácil de leer la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final pude resolver el problema, era más simple de lo que imaginaba, el nombre de mi archivo era tkinter y eso causaba problemas a la hora de hacer la importación!

Answer (score 0):

¿Estás seguro de que tienes instalada la versión 3 de Python?

Ten en cuenta que el módulo Tkinter se llama `Tkinter` (con 'T' mayúscula) en las versiones de Python 2.x, y `tkinter` (con 'T' minúscula) en Python 3.x.

Puedes comprobar tu versión de Python ejecutando el siguiente comando en la terminal:

```
python -v
```

Esto solucionaría tu error:

```
try:
    # Para versiones de Python2
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # Para versiones de Python3
    from tkinter import *
```

Comment: Sí, lo primero que hice fue desinstalar e instalar de nuevo python en su version 3.7.4 :/

Comment: ¿Has probado el código?

Comment: Sí ya lo he intentado

Comment: ¿Qué error te aparece? Ve editando tu pregunta.

Comment: Listo, acabo de editarlo con el error que me aparece

Comment: Te está dando error porque tienes error de sintaxis. Copia el código entero que te puse en mi respuesta y pégalo tal cual.

Comment: Acabo de poner una captura de como me quedó, me sigue dando error cuando el Tkinter tiene la t mayuscula porque estoy usando la version 3 de python

Comment: Esos errores no me cuadran mucho... ¿has ejecutado de nuevo el script?

Comment: Sí pero lo primero que me marca es que no puedo usar la T mayúscula :/ he estado así por días